# When will `threading.RLock.acquire()` return None?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-multithreading

In the Python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.RLock.acquire), it states that

> If more than one thread is blocked waiting until the lock is unlocked, only one at a time will be able to grab ownership of the lock. **There is no return value in this case.**

But in *which* case?

I experimented with the following code in IPython:

```py
import time, threading

def func(rlock):
    print(rlock.acquire())
    for i in range(4):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
    rlock.release()
    print('done')

rlock = threading.RLock()


# 2 threads
threading.Thread(target=func, args=[rl]).start()
threading.Thread(target=func, args=[rl]).start()
```

One thread starts to run after `rlock` released, and then another:

```py
rlock.release()
```

Output

```
True
0
1
2
3
done
True
0
1
2
3
done
```

In both threads `rlock.acquire()` got return value `True`.

Looking for an example where `rlock.acqure()` has no return value (return None)?

Comment: Hi Frozen Flame, I know this is a bit old question but could you please check my answer and check if it fits your question or you have any further doubt? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is a misunderstanding. The docs says:

> If more than one thread is blocked waiting until the lock is unlocked, only one at a time will be able to grab ownership of the lock. There is **no return value** in this case.

`no return value` is different from returning `None`. It actually **doesn't return anything**, not even `None`, due to the function being **blocked until the lock is acquired**.

Which the docs intends to say is that there's no a different return value for those situations, but a blocking behaviour. That's also the reason for this very same paragraph not specifying any return value but explaining the blocking procedure (since this paragraph is for no arguments, which will apply `blocking=True` as default).

Therefore, as summary:

- For `blocking=True`

  - `acquire()` -> if lock is available -> returns `True`
  - `acquire()` -> if lock isn't available -> **blocks until available**, then return `True`
- For `blocking=False`

  - `acquire()` -> if lock is available -> returns `True`
  - `acquire()` -> if lock isn't available -> returns `False`

With all this in mind, the answer to your question `when will RLock.acquire() return None?` would be `it doesn't` ;)

Comment: `adquire() -> if lock is available -> returns True` ...typo? ... I guess you intend to type acquire .. instead of adquire?